# Looping through a list of hosts and commands in Paramiko and store the result in excel with column headers

Tags: python, paramiko, xlwt

I have a file which has a list of hosts and I have another file which has a list of commands.I am trying to loop through host file and run all the commands in the command file using paramiko.The commands are basically checking parameters like uptime,current cpu,number of users logged in etc. This is the code that I have :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import paramiko


username = "log_me_in"
password = "secret"

# Opens files in read mode
f1 = open(hostfile,"r")
f2 = open(commandfile,"r")

# Creates list based on f1 and f2
devices = f1.readlines()
commands = f2.readlines()



for device in devices:
    device = device.rstrip()
    for command in commands:
        command = command.rstrip()
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(device, username=username, password=password)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        output = stdout.read()
        data =[]
        data.append(output)
        ssh.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

The problem I have is after I execute the commands on the remote machine.I want the stdout of each command that is executed to be stored in an excel sheet in one row for each device [image: description here]like this.
I have heard of python libraries like xlwt but was looking for help on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to write a CSV file and then import it from Excel? It's much easier (as `csv` is part of Python's standard library)

Comment: @Ricardo..yes..even that is fine..would you know how to do that ?

Comment: Could you add an example of what `output` looks like? You need to break it into components, and not knowing the format...

Comment: I having problem when  data.append(output) call only last value will be appended which is output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the next two pieces of code, I'll assume the existence of the following:

```
header = ["Device Name", "Uptime", "CPU", "Count of users logged in"]
data = [
    ('ns1', '200 days', '10%', '15'),
    ('ns2', '23 days', '12%', '23'),
    ('ns3', '45 days', '56%', '108')
]
```

Using CSV makes it for a bit easier code and it's easy to deploy on any machine, because it doesn't require to install any further package (`csv` comes standard with Python):

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    spamwriter.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

would produce the following `output.csv` file:

```
Device Name,Uptime,CPU,Count of users logged in
ns1,200 days,10%,15
ns2,23 days,12%,23
ns3,45 days,56%,108
```

Now, if you really want to use `xlwt`, here would be the equivalent (adding extra yellow background color for the header):

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet("foobar")

# Put the header in the appropriate cells...
style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore-colour yellow')
for col, text in enumerate(header):
    sheet.write(0, col, text, style)

# Now, let's write the contents

for row, data_in_row in enumerate(data):
    for col, text in enumerate(data_in_row):
        sheet.write(row + 1, col, text)

book.save("example.xls")
```

Comment: @Ricardo.. while this is really helpful,I have hit a few roadblocks.I do not know the data to be entered in the csv beforehand.I need to store the paramiko output for each device in an array and then write this to the csv which because of my limited python knowledge,i am not sure how to do. Also some of the command outputs already have commas in them..will this screw up the writing to the csv file ?

Comment: Well, that's just example data. If you'd expand your question showing some sample data, then it would be easier to answer :)

Comment: Ok... I've given you also an example of how to work with `xlwt`. All it takes now is to convert your input to something those two can work with (but I still need a sample of your input)

Comment: @Ricardo..I tried defining an empty list(see modified code) and tried appending the values into it for each output in the loop..not working as I expected..any pointers..?

Comment: Ricardo,I got this working..creating a list of tuples for the data and posted this to the excel..thanks for your help on this..

Comment: Good! BTW, you may want to have a look on `XlsxWriter`, another Python module that looks a little bit more modern and up do date, if you want to produce Office 2007+ Excel stuff.